# select data from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql="SELECT * 
            FROM jobs 
      INNER JOIN job_resp ON jobs.job_id = job_resp.job_id 
           WHERE jobs.job_id = $job_id";
```

Is this query is correct?

Comment: Hi, im curious ... shouldn't "echo $rows['job_titel'];" be inside the while{} ??

Comment: It actually is. The end bracket is later

Comment: Can you use echo to give us a print out of the query? Does your query get correcty the id parameter from the form?

Answer (score 0):

try to use below query:

```
$sql="SELECT j.*, jr.*
            FROM jobs as j
      INNER JOIN job_resp as jr ON j.job_id = jr.job_id 
           WHERE j.job_id ='".$job_id."'";
```

But you should avoid *, try to use field name as j.id, j.job_titel etc.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() will return FALSE on error.
check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

I think in your case, no result returned is not necessarily to be an error.
Therefore you can see no data showing plus the "successful" notice.

Comment: I would tend to agree that the cause may be there just isn't any valid results.  The inner join is going to return ONLY rows that match the join criteria.  Just to check the basics: make sure the jobID you're passing in is actually referenced in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is vulnerable to sql injection

```
$job_id=$_GET['job_id'];

// should be
$job_id=(int)$_GET['job_id'];
// or
$job_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['job_id']);
```

depending on the data type of jobid.

Also you are echoing rows before you declared it, so it wont work. it seems like it should be inside the while loop

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<li>".$rows['job_res']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```